# Windows Phone emulator is not supported on this computer because of GPU

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

It says that my computer does not support the XNA applications, but I want to debug an usual application (even if I launch the emulator stand-alone, it says it too). And when I'm pressing OK to conitunue, it's restarting and repeats it for inf times. What's wrong?

Comment: How well does the spec of your PC stack up to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524(v=vs.92).aspx? Especially with regards to system RAM - 3GB total with 1.5GB free?

Comment: I had a Beta2 running well on it (without XNA, of course)

Comment: Atom N270, 1.5 Gb RAM, Intel 945

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7 emulator has [requirements of its own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626524%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), higher than XNA Reach profile. The steepest is that it requires a DirectX10 capable GPU.

Netbook PCs lack this kind of hardware, so WP7 debugging is not possible without a proper phone.